# Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : No cluster endpoint is reachable, please check if there is connectivity/firewall/DNS issue

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, azure, visual-studio-2017, microservices

I went through this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-deploy-app-to-party-cluster) for creating & deploying the application into Party Cluster using Visual Studio 2017 & Powershell.

Now I am stuck with the following error in Power shell & Visual Studio :

**Power Shell :**

[image]

**Visual Studio 2017 :**

[image]

**NB :** I tried this [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTQNt.jpg) in my application, But getting the same result. Any other solution ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I went through this document : [Party Cluster](https://try.servicefabric.azure.com)

> Party Cluster runs for an hour ( Around 1 hour ), Then it's
>   automatically taken down. At that point, all our applications will be
>   removed and We will have to connect to a new cluster to keep partying.
>   We can only connect to one party cluster at a time.